# Replace all characters between two delimiters using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace all characters between two delimiters with another character using regex. The replacement should have the same length as the removed string.

```
String string1 = "any prefix [tag=foo]bar[/tag] any suffix";
String string2 = "any prefix [tag=foo]longerbar[/tag] any suffix";
String output1 = string1.replaceAll(???, "*");
String output2 = string2.replaceAll(???, "*");
```

The expected outputs would be:

```
output1: "any prefix [tag=foo]***[/tag] any suffix"  
output2: "any prefix [tag=foo]*********[/tag] any suffix"
```

I've tried `"\\\\\[tag=.\*?](.\*?)\\\\[/tag]"` but this replaces the whole sequence with a single `"\*"`.
I think that `"(.\*?)"` is the problem here because it captures everything at once.

How would I write something that replaces every character separately?

Comment: You'd need a callback to replace `*` times the length of the capture group. But, Java doesn't have regex replace callbacks. But, there is a workaround.

Comment: If regex is not really important, you can use substring with some logic, by this you can do your task

Comment: The problem is that regex is important in this case because I got a whole list of formatting that I can simply loop through and I don't want to break that for speacial cases

Comment: No, looks like I got the formatting wrong. I added the backslash to escape the  `*` because some parts were shown bold in the preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\w(?=\w*?\[)
```

which would match all characters before a "[\"

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/megrY9/1/),  [online compiler demo](https://ideone.com/2StzsV)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the chars inside, one by one and replace them by * :

```
public static String replaceByStar(String str) {
    String pattern = "(.*\\[tag=.*\\].*)\\w(.*\\[\\/tag\\].*)";
    while (str.matches(pattern)) {
        str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "$1*$2");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Use like this it will print your tx2 expected outputs :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(replaceByStar("any prefix [tag=foo]bar[/tag] any suffix"));
    System.out.println(replaceByStar("any prefix [tag=foo]loooongerbar[/tag] any suffix"));
}
```

---

So the pattern `"(.*\\[tag=.*\\].*)\\w(.*\\[\\/tag\\].*)"` :

- `(.*\\[tag=.*\\].*)` capture the beginning, with eventually some char in the middle
- `\\w` is for the char you want to replace
- `(.*\\[\\/tag\\].*)` capture the end, with eventually some char in the middle

---

The substitution `$1*$2`:

The pattern is `(text$1)oneChar(text$2)` and it will replace by `(text$1)*(text$2)`

Comment: This works very well but I forgot to mention that I'd prefer solution that works in one line with "replaceAll(pattern, replacement)" because I need to be able to add it to a list of formatting codes to loop through